# What's the difference between <binding> and <portType> in WSDL?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

Both `<binding>` and `<portType>` seem to define an operation and its message. I don't quite understand, why are they both necessary?

Comment: This is a good question, I don't think any of the answers below seem to address it. Distinguishing them only makes sense if there's a many to many relationship, which seems to be impossible when the <binding> tag can only reference one portType. There's probably a historical reason, rather than a practical one.

Answer (score 39):

**portType**  (Analogs to Java interface)

- PortType is an abstraction part of WSDL.
- An abstract set of operations supported by one or more endpoints.

**binding**

- Binding is an concrete part of WSDL.
- Describes how the operation is invoked by specifying concrete protocol and data format specifications for the operations and messages.
- [bindings are three types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-wsdl12-bindings-20020709/)

  1. [**SOAP Binding:**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-wsdl12-bindings-20020709/#_soap-b)
     SOAP binding allows either [`document` or `rpc` style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28407517/1697099) with either `encoding` or `literal`. **Encoding** indicates how a data value should be encoded in an XML format (These rules specify how "something" is encoded/serialized to XML and then later decoded/de-serialized from XML back to "something"). **Literal** means that the data is serialized according to a schema (this is just plain XML data). With transportation type http, jms, smtp...
  2. [**HTTP GET & POST binding:**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-wsdl12-bindings-20020709/#_http)
     WSDL includes a binding for HTTP 1.1's GET and POST verbs in order to describe the interaction between a Web Browser and a web site.
  3. [**MIME binding:**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-wsdl12-bindings-20020709/#_mime) 
     WSDL includes a way to bind abstract types to concrete messages in some MIME format.

---

[image]

In WSDL 2.0 :

- PortTypes renamed to interfaces
- Ports renamed to endpoints
- Removed message constructs

[*Source*](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/web_services/ws_wsdlstructure.html)

---

Useful links

- [WSDL Reading, a Beginner's Guide](http://www.predic8.com/wsdl-reading.htm)
- [W3C: Web Services Description Language (WSDL) 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)
- [W3C: Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/)

Answer (score 26):

**Interfaces (wsdl:portType)**

The WSDL portType element defines a group of operations (sometimes known as an interface).

The operation elements contain a combination of input and output elements. There can be a fault element when you have an output element. The order of these elements defines the message exchange pattern (MEP) (One-way, Request – Response, etc)

[image]

**wsdl:binding**

The WSDL binding element describes the concrete details of using a particular portType with a given protocol.

[image]

Comment: You could also have cited your source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx

Answer (score 13):

PortType defines the **abstract interface** of a web service.
Conceptually it is like a Java interface since it defines an abstract type and related methods.
In WSDL the port type is **implemented** by the binding and service elements which indicate the protocols, encoding schemes etc to be used by a **web service implementation**
I.e. the binding specifies **concrete implementation details** and essentially maps a portType to a set of protocols (HTTP and SOAP) message styles (Document/RPC) and encodings (literal)
Is the distiction clear now?

Comment: Should line 1 read 'The Port Type defines the abstract interface of a web service'?

Comment: The analogy was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

***portType***
A ***single Web service*** can support a ***number of different protocols***. The structure of the data depends on the protocol that you use to invoke the Web service. Because of this, you need a way to map from the operations to the ***endpoints*** from which they can be accessed. The ***portType*** element takes care of this mapping.

You can place a portType definition for each of the protocols available to you for this Web service. For instance, you can have individual portType definitions for using ***SOAP, HTTP-POST, and HTTP-GET***. The operation name is the method available from the Web service.

***binding***
You can define how the end user binds to a port where the operation is obtainable. You do this by using the  element.

Answer (score 2):

wsdl:portType goes with wsdl:operation
i.e. we are in the realms of messages and xml as such

but wsdl:binding goes with soap:binding and soap:operation
i.e. we are in the realm of encoding, addresses, headers and rpc

e.g. from : http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap-b

```
 <binding name="StockQuoteSoap" type="tns:StockQuotePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://example.com/smtp"/>
        <operation name="SubscribeToQuotes">
           <input message="tns:SubscribeToQuotes">
               <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
               <soap:header message="tns:SubscribeToQuotes" part="subscribeheader" use="literal"/>
```

.....

```
<binding name="StockQuoteSoapBinding" type="tns:StockQuotePortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="GetTradePrice">
       <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/GetTradePrice"/>
       <input>
           <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/stockquote"
                      encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
```

...

and from paragraph 3.2 all possible details about lower level communication stuff:

The SOAP Binding extends WSDL with the following extension elements:

```
<definitions .... >
    <binding .... >
        <soap:binding style="rpc|document" transport="uri">
        <operation .... >
           <soap:operation soapAction="uri"? style="rpc|document"?>?
           <input>
               <soap:body parts="nmtokens"? use="literal|encoded"
                          encodingStyle="uri-list"? namespace="uri"?>
               <soap:header message="qname" part="nmtoken" use="literal|encoded"
                            encodingStyle="uri-list"? namespace="uri"?>*
                 <soap:headerfault message="qname" part="nmtoken" use="literal|encoded"
                                   encodingStyle="uri-list"? namespace="uri"?/>*
               <soap:header>                                
           </input>
           <output>
               <soap:body parts="nmtokens"? use="literal|encoded"
                          encodingStyle="uri-list"? namespace="uri"?>
               <soap:header message="qname" part="nmtoken" use="literal|encoded"
                            encodingStyle="uri-list"? namespace="uri"?>*
                 <soap:headerfault message="qname" part="nmtoken" use="literal|encoded"
                                   encodingStyle="uri-list"? namespace="uri"?/>*
               <soap:header>                                
           </output>
           <fault>*
               <soap:fault name="nmtoken" use="literal|encoded"
                           encodingStyle="uri-list"? namespace="uri"?>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <port .... >
        <soap:address location="uri"/> 
    </port>
</definitions>
```